# Finding 0 - (Python Testing) random.uniform(0,1) Double Precision Floating Point

Tags: python, random, ieee-754, proof

This has been making my head hurt. I have also seen a detailed post on stack overflow about this situation that is a few years old and I would like to highlight some of the flaws from the discussions.
I will highlight them in the next section. But the problem is outlined below.

I am trying to find out if the random.uniform(0,1) function from the random library,

```
import random
```

can indeed output a value of 0 given a range greater than 0 excluding special case random.uniform(0,0) (range here is 0).

**Special Case**

```
>>>random.uniform(0,0) 
0.0
```

**Test**

```
>>>random.uniform(0,1)
0.11689643963821128
```

Upon doing some research about IEEE 754 standard for double precision floating point numbers which are used in python for this function, I have not been able to prove that 0 cannot be a result of random.uniform(x,y) where (x!=y and x,y !=0)*See expectation*.

But this leads me to another question why does IEEE754 standard round to 0 if and only if it is 0, but not any other number unless proving otherwise obviously.

I want to say it's impossible, but wondering what you guys think.

I have used **[this](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)** website to check for a few numbers too but with no luck.

I have tried using various loops some even give me outputs closer to 1 when using this function, I need to do some more testing before backing this up, but using values like that on the website provided above, provide weird values.

The link to the old stackoverflow thread can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58241868/can-random-uniform0-1-ever-generate-0-or-1)**

One of the responses suggest that

```
>>> random.uniform(0., 5e-324)
0.0
```

`will indeed give you a value of 0 however it can also give you this (is it a 50% chance?)`

```
>>> random.uniform(0., 5e-324)
5e-324
```

other times it has shown to me to be infinite in VS Code Debugger when used in a loop until reaching 0.0 for some reason upon a random interval.

So this also begs the question does python really process 324 digits of precision using the uniform specification without needing to specify that we really want a range between 0 and 5e-324.
With an integer range it only produces about 16 digits of precision.

There are some other points that I have read through on the older thread, but I am struggling to relate here to it.

So can random.uniform(0,1) actually produce 0.0?
If you have tried experimenting or researching this in other languages, please share your thoughts and results.

(I may be making more edits to this question to make implement further testing or clearing and further explaining to some points made)

Comment: By definition, yes, `uniform` can return the low end, but not the high end.  That's documented.  No, there are certainly not 324 digits of precision.  A double has about 17 digits.  0.00000001 will round to 0 in Python.  You should perhaps show more of the code you're playing with.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts, I was thinking too how on earth would it be using 324 digits of precison, need to do some more digging. I may post some more of the code I am playing with to show some erroneous/unintended results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not have a formal specification, and the behavior of `random.uniform` is not well specified. Given `a` and `b` with `a` ≤ 0 < `b`, I expect `random.uniform(a, b)` should be able to return zero, based on my minimum quality expectations. And, since it supports inverted ranges, it should also be able to return zero with `a` and `b` with `b` < 0 ≤ `a`.

Discussion in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) suggest that `random.uniform(a, b)` is computed as `a + (b-a) * random.random()`. It also says `random.random()` returns a number in [0, 1). This is an incomplete specification for `random.random()`, and my comments about that for JavaScript/ECMAScript are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089553/what-are-the-chances-of-math-random-returning-0/52095861#52095861). My suspicion would be that `random.random()` prepares a 53-bit integer drawn from a uniform distribution<sup>2</sup>, converts it to the IEEE-754 binary64 (“double precision”) format and divides it by 2<sup>53</sup>.

If `random.uniform(a, b)` is computed as `a + (b-a) * random.random()`, then floating-point rounding can, in general, produce `b` as a result, so the output range is not purely [`a`, `b`). The underlying mathematics, if computed with infinite precision, would never produce `b` as a result, but, because a limited-precision format is used, the roundings in the multiplication and in the addition can result in `b` being produced.

> One of the responses suggest that … `random.uniform(0., 5e-324)` … will indeed give you a value of 0 however it can also give you this (is it a 50% chance?)

When `5e-324` is converted to IEEE-754 binary64, the result is 2<sup>−1074</sup>, approximately 4.940656•10−324. There are no representable values between 0 and 2<sup>−1074</sup>. Computing `random.uniform(0, 5e-324)` as described above yields 0 + (2<sup>−1074</sup>−0)•`random.random()` rounded to the nearest representable value. This equals  2<sup>−1074</sup>•`random.random()` rounded to the nearest representable value. If `random.random()` is in [0, ½], this will round to 0.<sup>1</sup> If it is in (½, 1), it will round to 2<sup>−1074</sup>. There are 2<sup>52</sup>+1 representable numbers in [0, ½] and 2<sup>52</sup>−1 representable numbers in (½, 1). So the chance of getting 0 is not 50%; it is slightly greater, (2<sup>52</sup>+1)/2<sup>53</sup> = ½+2<sup>−53</sup>.

> So this also begs the question does python really process 324 digits of precision…

No. Under the assumptions above, a Python implementation takes 53 bits for `random.random()` and then computes `a + (b-a)*random.random()`. When you evaluate `random.uniform(0., 5e-324)`, the small result is caused by scaling after the random number is selected for `random.random()`. It is not present in the selection of the random number.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Mark Dickinson confirmed this for CPython in a comment: “We draw two 32-bit unsigned ints from the underlying Mersenne Twister generator, then combine the top 27 bits of the first with the top 26 bits of the second (probably out of latent superstition about lack of randomness in low-order bits of PRNGs, which certainly applies to LCGs, but not to Mersenne Twister),”  also linking to [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8fe1a88e6ac3df20ad6bb96dd7e25aa18f2f438a/Modules/_randommodule.c#L176-L182):

```
static PyObject *
_random_Random_random_impl(RandomObject *self)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=117ff99ee53d755c input=afb2a59cbbb00349]*/
{
    uint32_t a=genrand_uint32(self)>>5, b=genrand_uint32(self)>>6;
    return PyFloat_FromDouble((a*67108864.0+b)*(1.0/9007199254740992.0));
}
```

<sup>2</sup> In the border case, 2<sup>−1074</sup>•½ would yield 2<sup>−1075</sup> with real-number arithmetic. This result is exactly halfway between the two nearest representable values, 0 and 2<sup>−1074</sup>. The default rounding rule says, in case of ties, to round to the neighbor with the even low digit, so 0 is chosen.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this answer, I will be diving deeper into this topic, I really like this depth of explanation to help in understanding how this algorithm works of generating the random value. I am even more curious.

Comment: I would like to further discuss your reasoning behind generating a 53 bit integer and dividing by 2^53. Could you walk me through this with your understanding and raise an example of how this would work. And since you suggest that 0 would be
a theoretical possible outcome of random.uniform(0,1). What kind of inputs would it have to take, before division takes place after being converted to an IEEE number, The numerator would have to be 0 , (or simply 0 represented with 53 bits)?

Comment: Does the conversion you suggested to an IEEE 754 number include dividing by 2^53, or are you suggesting there is an unknown conversion occurring?

Comment: Reading through your answer once again, and since I can't edit my previous comments, you provided an example already with 5e-324 so please ignore the question about providing an example, and about the conversion, I am still unsure how this is formatted, but its definitely not unknown. But what I was aiming for is actually meeting the threshold of getting 0 every time, is there a possible input of this? Or Without needing to specify so many digits of precision. This could help in narrowing down the likeliness of random.uniform(0,1) truly generating a value of 0.

Comment: Since you stated, it uses a limited precision system so if it starts by generating a number from a limited set of numbers between 0 to 1 BEFORE conversion to IEEE 754 is it possible that the threshold of a binary value rounding to 0 is not included (to be clear for the specific case of the range)making the conversion AFTER to IEEE 754 not possible? Or is my understanding of this wrong. Making it dependent on the software of what value it "randomizes".

Comment: @CarpeDiem: My suspicion is that `random.random()` gets 53 bits from whatever internal generator it has. I suspect 53 bits because the IEEE-754 binary format represents floating-point numbers as 53-bit numbers with scaling by a power of two and a + or − sign. So taking 53 bits fits the format. Then the 53 bits are converting to floating-point. Since they fit in the format, there is no rounding error. That would produce a number in [0, 2^53). To get a number in [0, 1), it divides by 2^53. The result is zero if and only if the 53 bits were all zero.

Comment: @CarpeDiem: Re “But what I was aiming for is actually meeting the threshold of getting 0 every time”: I do not know what you mean by getting 0 “every time.” The random number generators should generate practically independent values. Getting multiple zeros in a row would be rare. Getting zeros “every time” would indicate a bug.

Comment: @CarpeDiem: Re “is there a possible input of this?”: I do not know what you mean. Once seeded, the random number generation routines do not have inputs. Unless you mean the parameters for requesting a certain range. To get zero every time, you could use `random.uniform(0, 0)`. I do not see what use that would be.

Comment: Thank you for stating why you suggest it is represented by a 53 bit number as for the "getting zero everytime" I mean the limit you would have to enter to round to 0 everytime without the maximum value being  0. For example 5e-324 but even that does not print 0 at all times. If you understand where I am going with this. Or a number that is the next closest to 0 that uses the ieee 754 range

Comment: "My suspicion would be that random.random() prepares a 53-bit integer drawn from a uniform distribution" <- Indeed that's what happens, at least for CPython. We draw two 32-bit unsigned ints from the underlying Mersenne Twister generator, then combine the top 27 bits of the first with the top 26 bits of the second (probably out of latent superstition about lack of randomness in low-order bits of PRNGs, which certainly applies to LCGs, but not to Mersenne Twister). The code is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8fe1a88e6ac3df20ad6bb96dd7e25aa18f2f438a/Modules/_randommodule.c#L176-L182